# Azure website restore error

Tags: azure, backup, azure-web-app-service, restore

I am getting the following error when restoring a website backup (deployment slot). I am making the backup and trying to restore it using the azure management portal:

> Failed to restore the Backup to App xxx(xxxstaging), Check your app
>   Custom HostNames, Databases and Connection strings. Restore operation 
>   may fail if there are conflicts between source and destination

The audit log shows the following info:

> statusCode:BadRequest serviceRequestId:
>   statusMessage:{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"**The provided URI is
>   not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https and it has to have
>   2 segments)**.","Target":null,"Details":[{"Message":"The provided URI
>   is not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https and it has to
>   have 2
>   segments)."},{"Code":"BadRequest"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The
>   provided URI is not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https
>   and it has to have 2
>   segments).","ExtendedCode":"54103","MessageTemplate":"The provided URI
>   is not a SAS URL for a container (it needs to be https and it has to
>   have 2
>   segments).","Parameters":[],"InnerErrors":null}}],"Innererror":null}

It is very strange because it was working in the past, and it happens in one deployment slot, nothing changes between the backup and the restore (same hostname, database and connection string, same storage account, same subscription...)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps it is due to some breaking changes introduced by Azure in the recent updates.

From your error description, it seems like the root cause of the problem is due to the provided URI is not a SAS URL for a container.

I suggest you to take a look at the Examples of SAS URLs from a very recent Microsoft blog post as below.
[Examples of SAS URIs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#examples-of-sas-uris)

Hope this helps.